# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: net.jpountz.util.Utils.checkRange

Tags: pyspark, spark-streaming

i use spark-streaming 2.2.0 with python.  and read data from kafka(2.11-0.10.0.0) cluster.
   and i submit a python script with 
   spark-submit --jars  spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly_2.11-2.2.0.jar hodor.py
   the spark report a error message

```
17/08/04 10:52:00 ERROR Utils: Uncaught exception in thread stdout 
writer for python
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: net.jpountz.util.Utils.checkRange([BII)V
at org.apache.kafka.common.message.KafkaLZ4BlockInputStream.read(KafkaLZ4BlockInputStream.java:176)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
at kafka.message.ByteBufferMessageSet$$anonfun$decompress$1.apply$mcI$sp(ByteBufferMessageSet.scala:67)
at kafka.message.ByteBufferMessageSet$$anonfun$decompress$1.apply(ByteBufferMessageSet.scala:67)
at kafka.message.ByteBufferMessageSet$$anonfun$decompress$1.apply(ByteBufferMessageSet.scala:67)
at scala.collection.immutable.Stream$.continually(Stream.scala:1279)
at kafka.message.ByteBufferMessageSet$.decompress(ByteBufferMessageSet.scala:67)
at kafka.message.ByteBufferMessageSet$$anon$1.makeNextOuter(ByteBufferMessageSet.scala:179)
at kafka.message.ByteBufferMessageSet$$anon$1.makeNext(ByteBufferMessageSet.scala:192)
at kafka.message.ByteBufferMessageSet$$anon$1.makeNext(ByteBufferMessageSet.scala:146)
at kafka.utils.IteratorTemplate.maybeComputeNext(IteratorTemplate.scala:66)
at kafka.utils.IteratorTemplate.hasNext(IteratorTemplate.scala:58)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$18.hasNext(Iterator.scala:764)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaRDD$KafkaRDDIterator.getNext(KafkaRDD.scala:214)
at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.hasNext(NextIterator.scala:73)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.foreach(NextIterator.scala:21)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:509)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$3.apply(PythonRDD.scala:333)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1954)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRDD.scala:269)
```

i think it maybe caused with lz4 version conflict.
    spark depend on net.jpountz.lz4 1.3.0
    but kafka depend on net.jpountz.lz4 1.2.0

how can i fix it?

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue when upgrading to spark 2.3.0 (join two streams with Structured Streaming)

This is the error:

> NoSuchMethodError: net.jpountz.lz4.LZ4BlockInputStream.init<>

I am using Maven, so the solution was to add the oldest dependency of the two (spark 2.3 used 1.4.0, kafka used 1.3.0), to the **pom.xml** of my main project.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.jpountz.lz4</groupId>
    <artifactId>lz4</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

What build tool are you using on that project? You should leave only one of the versions on your app's classpath, but how to do that will depend on the build tool. [Maven](https://benkiew.wordpress.com/2015/01/20/maven-force-the-exclusion-of-dependencies/)? [Gradle](http://www.concretepage.com/build-tools/gradle/gradle-exclude-transitive-dependency-example)? Either way you'll have to check which version of that lib will work for both components.

Comment: i follow the kafka Integration guide http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-0-8-integration.html
it told to use the spark-submit command for this job.