# PYSAPRK python java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: net.jpountz.lz4.LZ4BlockInputStream.<init>(Ljava/io/InputStream;Z)V

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, nosuchmethoderror

This question for PySpark alone is not answered. So I'm asking again. 
I'm doing a simple `wordcount.py` example using PySpark from [Spark download](https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html).

The code is down below. I did a `mvn clean install` and used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45498075/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-net-jpountz-util-utils-checkrange) suggestion and added dependency to my pom.xml under examples of spark folder. And `mvn install` again.

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.jpountz.lz4</groupId>
  <artifactId>lz4</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

```py
from __future__ import print_function

import sys
from operator import add

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
if __name__ == "__main__":
if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print("Usage: wordcount <file>", file=sys.stderr)
    sys.exit(-1)

spark = SparkSession\
    .builder\
    .appName("PythonWordCount")\
    .getOrCreate()

lines = spark.read.text(sys.argv[1]).rdd.map(lambda r: r[0])
counts = lines.flatMap(lambda x: x.split(' ')) \
              .map(lambda x: (x, 1)) \
              .reduceByKey(add)
output = counts.collect()
for (word, count) in output:
    print("%s: %i" % (word, count))

spark.stop()
```

The Error I get is :

```
 2018-10-29 15:19:01 ERROR Utils:91 - Uncaught exception in thread stdout writer for python
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: net.jpountz.lz4.LZ4BlockInputStream.<init>(Ljava/io/InputStream;Z)V
    at org.apache.spark.io.LZ4CompressionCodec.compressedInputStream(CompressionCodec.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializerManager.wrapForCompression(SerializerManager.scala:163)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializerManager.wrapStream(SerializerManager.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.BlockStoreShuffleReader$$anonfun$2.apply(BlockStoreShuffleReader.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.BlockStoreShuffleReader$$anonfun$2.apply(BlockStoreShuffleReader.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.next(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:417)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.next(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:61)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator.hasNext(CompletionIterator.scala:32)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:204)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$2.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRunner.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$1.apply(PythonRunner.scala:215)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1988)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRunner.scala:170)
Exception in thread "stdout writer for python" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: net.jpountz.lz4.LZ4BlockInputStream.<init>(Ljava/io/InputStream;Z)V
    at org.apache.spark.io.LZ4CompressionCodec.compressedInputStream(CompressionCodec.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializerManager.wrapForCompression(SerializerManager.scala:163)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializerManager.wrapStream(SerializerManager.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.BlockStoreShuffleReader$$anonfun$2.apply(BlockStoreShuffleReader.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.BlockStoreShuffleReader$$anonfun$2.apply(BlockStoreShuffleReader.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.next(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:417)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.next(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:61)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator.hasNext(CompletionIterator.scala:32)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:204)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$2.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRunner.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$1.apply(PythonRunner.scala:215)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1988)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRunner.scala:170)
^C2018-10-29 15:19:10 INFO  SparkContext:54 - Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/spark-2.3.0/spark/examples/src/main/python/wordcount.py", line 40, in <module>
    output = counts.collect()
```

Comment: Why would you even use Maven? Are your trying to build Spark? If that's it please follow [Building Spark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/building-spark.html). Otherwise download pre-built binaries.

Comment: i'm not trying to build spark. I'm trying to do the same in scala too, i get the same error.    scala> counts.collect()
2018-11-02 15:44:06 ERROR Executor:91 - Exception in task 0.0 in stage 9.0 (TID 18)
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: net.jpountz.lz4.LZ4BlockInputStream.<init>(Ljava/io/InputStream;Z)V

Comment: @user10465355: I followed this suggestion to build spark https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45498075/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-net-jpountz-util-utils-checkrange?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1):

I upgraded spark to 2.3.2 and the error looks resolved.

Example:

> scala> val lines = sc.parallelize(Array(('a', 1), ('a', 1), ('b', 1)))
>
> lines: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Char, Int)] =ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at :24
>
> scala> val y = lines.reduceByKey((x,y) =>(x+y))
>
> y: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Char, Int)] = ShuffledRDD[1] at reduceByKey
>   at :25
>
> scala> y.collect() res0: Array[(Char, Int)] = Array((a,2), (b,1))

works..!